# Finding number of cells in a Column in Excel

Tags: java, jxl

I want to find the number of contents in a column from Excel File.

Example

```
Location Device Second
1         A      10
2         B       20
3                 30
```

Now, I want that it should display,
Location: 3
Device: 2
Second: 3

I am using jxl.

```
 Workbook existingWorkbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File(filename1));
        WritableWorkbook workbookCopy = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File(filename1), existingWorkbook);
        WritableSheet sheetToEdit = workbookCopy.getSheet(0);

     int n=   sheetToEdit.getcolumns();
     System.out.println(n);

        workbookCopy.write();
        workbookCopy.close();
```

Here, I am getting, only the number of columns,

Can u tell me, how I can do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don't think there's a direct way to do that beyond manual counting and determining empty cells:

```
Workbook existingWorkbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File(filename1));
WritableWorkbook workbookCopy = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File(filename1), existingWorkbook);
WritableSheet sheetToEdit = workbookCopy.getSheet(0);

for (int i=0; i<sheetToEdit.getcolumns(); i++) {
    int columnCount = 0;
    for (Cell cell : sheetToEdit.getColumn(i))
        if (!cell.getContents().equals(""))
            columnCount++;
    System.out.println(columnCount);
}

workbookCopy.write();
workbookCopy.close();
```

Comment: If there are 100 column and I only want to find the number for the 2nd column, then how can I do. As  sheetToEdit.getcolumns will take much time.

Comment: skip the outer for loop and use sheetToEdit.getRow(1)